# DJI Mobile SDK Way point mission configuration in order not to brake at every waypoint

Tags: dji-sdk

in our we Mission Planning APP based on Mobile SDK we need to define very dense way points (we have way points every 10 meters).
In that situation the aircraft behaviour is the following: once at the waypoint position it brakes and then accelarates again to go to the next waypoint.

Is there any configuration about the mission or about the way points able to avoid the stop at each waypoint? 
It is not possible to set a target speed on each waypoint, however is it possible not to brake at every waypoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is actually possible to do all of what you want with DJI SDK.

[`DJIWaypointMission`](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/ios/Classes/DJIWaypointMission.html) has a flight path mode property which takes two options: normal and curved. Normal flies the mission the way you expect, with stops between each waypoint. Curved however, will make the drone fly through the waypoints without stopping. The radius of the curve that the drone makes at each waypoint is configurable by changing the value at each waypoint.

[`DJIWaypoint`](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/ios/Classes/DJIWaypoint.html) has `coordinate`, `altitude` and `heading` fields which help specify the drone's position at that particular waypoint. It also has a `gimbalPitch` property which can help orient the pitch of the gimbal to what you want. The `speed` property will allow you to set the speed of the aircraft between two particular waypoints.

Now, instead of creating `DJIWaypointAction`s to take pictures, what you can do is set the [`shootPhotoDistance`](https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/ios/Classes/DJIWaypoint.html#/c:objc(cs)DJIWaypoint(py)shootPhotoDistanceInterval) property of each `DJIWaypoint` to some value greater than your maximum inter-waypoint distance. Doing this will instruct the drone to take one picture as soon as it reaches the waypoint (without stopping if your waypoint mission is curved).

---

So, in conclusion what you want to do is create a `WaypointMission` with a `curved` flight mode, and add the list of all your custom waypoints which have the `shootPhotoDistance` property set to a large distance.

Comment: Does work with all DJI drones like mavic pro? I read somewhere in doc it only works for inspire 1 and phantom series...

Answer (score 1):

The waypoint code uses stopping at each waypoint as the method to know that a waypoint has been reached. So programming the drone to go to a waypoint, the waypoint is reached, the drone stops, and then completes various actions such as taking a picture. 
If you do not want the drone to stop at each waypoint then use a curved path instead of a normal path. However in this instance, since using a curved path, the drone does not stop but it is also not possible to complete actions such as taking a picture at each waypoint. 
The usual method around this is to choose waypoints relatively far away from each other and then use timing to take a picture every couple of seconds. 
In addition be careful of wanting waypoints every 10m. The issue is one of precision/accuracy of the GPS system unless you are using RTK. If you are not using rtk then a specific waypoint lat/lng can frequently vary by a couple of meters between each flight depending on satellite lock and other factors.